# How to create custom page in admin opencart 3

Tags: opencart, opencart-3, opencart-module

I am trying to create a custom admin page under opencart admin section. But for any reason it is not working can anyone please help ?

I have created controller file under admin/controller/catalog/filterproducts.php
and the code is:

```
<?php
class ControllerCatalogFilterProducts extends Controller {
  public function index() {
    $this->load->language('catalog/filterproducts');

    $data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('heading_title'); 
    return $this->load->view('catalog/filter_products.tpl', $data);
  }
}
```

and in admin/view/template/catalog/filter_products.tpl I have code like:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-users"></i> <?php echo $heading_title; ?></h3>
  </div>
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td class="text-right">SrNo</td>
          <td>Product Name</td>
          <td>Quantity</td>
          <td>Price</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td class="text-right">1</td>
                  <td>Test Product</td>
                  <td>1</td>
                  <td>$1.00</td>
                </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the last file I have in admin/language/en-gb/catalog/filterproducts.php with code:

```
<?php
// Heading
$_['heading_title']          = 'Filter Products';
```

Comment: which is actual version of opencart ?

Comment: Version 3.0.3.1

Comment: but your file is .tpl not twig. once you update your code it working or not ? reply me. i think 2x version you have right now. i update code right now. check it.

Comment: working or not ?

Comment: I tried to change from tpl to twig but still not working even not showing any error in error_log too. Showing blank page.

Comment: what you have actual error. i think permission issue right. you go to usergroup -> Administrator and give permission. it will be 100% working.i have working well. you are working with local server or live server. ??? open link and see output https://prnt.sc/opzi5d

Comment: what happens MyPlayStudio? it working or not ?

Comment: Sorry for delay in response. That is not permission issue because I already done permission things. But still I am getting blank page with no error even not in error_log file.

Comment: is that solved or not ?